# A strange warning fire in Expo before starting the application

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I get this warning and the app shows a blank screen (does not open the starter screen)

here's the warning

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Directory for
> /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%4027mdmo7sn%2FIndaparty/ExponentAsset-7695aeab83089e2ceacc05dfa159a17f.ttf
> doesn't exist.]
>
> Stack trace:
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:99:50
> in fn
> node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.js:15:46
> in moduleName.methodInfo.name
> node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:105:50 in
> downloadAsync   node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in
> tryCatch   node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in
> invoke   node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in
> Promise$argument_0   node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in
> tryCallTwo   node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:23 in
> doResolve   node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:27 in
> Promise$argument_0
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:8 in exports.async
> node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:101:7 in
> downloadAsync   node_modules/expo-asset/build/PlatformUtils.js:45:50
> in _downloadAsyncManagedEnv
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
> node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:145:19 in
> Promise.resolve.then$argument_0
> node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
> node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in
> setImmediate$argument_0
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in
> _callTimer   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in
> _callImmediatesPass   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in
> callImmediates   [native code]:null in callImmediates
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6
> in __callImmediates
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6
> in __guard$argument_0
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10
> in __guard
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17
> in __guard$argument_0   [native code]:null in flushedQueue   [native
> code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue   ...

Environment info

OS : MacOS Catalina

Expo CLI version : 3.20.1

Expo SDK version : 37.0.0

I test on Android mobile (through last version of Expo client)

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Scratte , nice tip - I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple ,

by clearing the storage usage and cache which allocated by Expo client app

Comment: If that's the answer, please mark your question as being the answer, and provide an example how you executed the solution, and even better if you can explain why it worked.